# How to route to particular app details when i click on the app

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular6

I have Json data

`models: Array<Model> = [
    {
      name: 'kanban',
      version: '1',
      processes: [
        {
          name: 'kanban',
          version: '1',
          descrption: 'kanabn'
        },
        {
          name: 'kanban 2',
          version: '2',
          descrption: 'kanban 2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'gibier',
      version: '1',
      processes: [
        {
          name: 'gibier',
          version: '1',
          descrption: 'gibier'
        },
        {
          name: 'gibier 2',
          version: '2',
          descrption: 'gibier 2'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];`

so that by using this i have created a page by using

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" *ngFor="let app of models">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2>{{app.name}}</h2>
    <h4>{{app.version}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

So i got two **cards**

So when i click on one card i should get the particulars details of specific **appName**

```js
** App.module.Ts **

  {
    path: 'applicationDashboard',
    component: ApplicationDashboardComponent
  }, {
    path: 'applicationDashboard/:id',
    component: ApplicationDetailComponent
  },
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" *ngFor="let apps of models">
  <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let process of apps.processes">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="fadein">
          <div class="item-box" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(\'' + config.contextRoot + '/app/rest/models/' + process.id + '/thumbnail?version=' + imageVersion + '\')'}" (click)="showProcessDetails(process);" style="background-image: url(&quot;/activiti-app/app/rest/models/f6b21c92-81bb-4fc9-990f-852729e131f1/thumbnail?version=1533200931200&quot;);">
            <div class="actions">
              <span class="badge badge-secondary">v{{process.version}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <h3 class="truncate ng-binding" [title]="">
                {{process.name}}
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Model
} from '../../model';
import {
  ModelService
} from '../../model.service';
import {
  Route,
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application-detail',
  templateUrl: './application-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-detail.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  name;
  model: any;
  models: Array < Model > = [];
  constructor(private modelservice: ModelService, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.models = modelservice.getModel();
    this.name = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(this.name);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = this.models;
    console.log(this.model);
  }
  showProcessDetails(process) {
    console.log('keerthi', this.models.find(x => x.processes === process));
  }

}
```

I have written the above code for routing and displaying data.

What happening is:

**I can route to the correct page , But i am getting displayed all 4 processes in my json data without regarding to particular App**

can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Show your TypeScript Class File of ApplicationDetailComponent

Comment: i have added my `.ts` file @mrkernelpanic

Comment: Multiple things are wrong: 1st. Call `this.models = modelservice.getModel();` only in `ngOnInit` and also try to fetch your params in ngOnInit via Observable pattern.

Comment: Didn't got your point. I have written the call in `ngOnInit` @mrkernelpanic

Comment: How to retrieve Data of Kanban to another new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the name from id which i am routing to :

```
this.name = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

After that i have looped through the model and got the details by checking `this.name`

and in html also i used `*ngFor="let apps of model.processes"`

```
*ngIf="apps.name ==name"
```

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Model
} from '../../model';
import {
  ModelService
} from '../../model.service';
import {
  Route,
  ActivatedRoute,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application-detail',
  templateUrl: './application-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-detail.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  name;
  model: any;
  models: Array < Model > = [];
  constructor(private modelservice: ModelService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.name = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log('name', this.name);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.models = this.modelservice.getModel();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.models.length; i++) {
      if (this.name === this.models[i].name) {
        this.model = this.models[i];
        console.log('model:', this.model);
      }
    }
  }
  showProcessDetails(process) {
    this.router.navigate(['/process', process.name]);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar subheader">
      <h2>App definition Details :{{name}} </h2>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="col-4 preview-wrapper justify-content-start" *ngFor="let apps of model.processes">
      <div class="card" *ngIf="apps.name ==name">
        <div class="card-body app theme-1">
          <div class="app-content">
            <h3>{{apps.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{apps.details}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="backdrop">
            <i ng-show="!app.appDefinition.icon" class="icon icon-choice ng-hide"></i>
            <i ng-show="app.appDefinition.icon" class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="logo">
            <i ng-show="!app.appDefinition.icon" class="icon icon-choice ng-hide"></i>
            <i ng-show="app.appDefinition.icon" class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let process of model.processes">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="fadein">
              <div class="item-box" (click)="showProcessDetails(process);">
                <div class="actions">
                  <span class="badge badge-secondary">v{{process.version}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                  <h3 class="truncate">
                    {{process.name}}
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use just **`(click)`** instead of **`ng-click`** which is an angularjs syntax,

```
(click)="showProcessDetails(process);
```

Comment: still i am not getting specific processes of particular app, still i am getting all 4 processes @Sajeetharan

Comment: cannot be, since it is inside row it should send the specific one